# Bind Form Data as JSON String/String Array to Request Params In String

Tags: java, json, ajax, spring, spring-boot

I have a form which I would like to send to my controller via ajax:

```
<div class="row">
            <label for="username" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label my-auto">Username:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10 my-auto">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <label for="password" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label my-auto">Password:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10 my-auto">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="password" name="password">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" id="ratingRow">
            <label for="adminFoci" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label my-auto">User Rating:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-auto my-auto">
                <select class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true" name="adminFoci" id="adminFoci" title="Choose Foci">
                    <c:forEach items="${foci}" var="focus">
                        <option name="${focus.focusName}" value="">${focus.focusName}</option>
                    </c:forEach>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm my-auto">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="rating" name="rating">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-auto my-auto" id="ratingButtonRow">
                <div class="btn btn-info btn-sm" id="adminAddGroup">Add Rating</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <label for="adminUserGroups" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label my-auto">User's Groups:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-auto my-auto">
                <select class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true" id="adminUserGroups" name="groups" title="Choose Groups">
                    <c:forEach items="${groups}" var="group">
                        <option name="${group.groupName}" value="${group.groupName}">${group.groupName}</option>
                    </c:forEach>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label my-auto">User's Roles:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10 my-auto">
                <select class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true" id="adminUserRoles" name="roles" title="Choose Roles">
                    <c:forEach items="${user.roles}" var="role">
                        <option name="${role.name}" value="${role.name}">${role.name}</option>
                    </c:forEach>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I catch the form submit and serialize the form data:

```
$("#modalForm").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: form.attr('action'),
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify($(this).serializeArray()), 
            success: function(data)
            {
                table.row('.selected').ajax.reload();
            }
        });

    });
```

I then try to bind data of the json string array to request params in my controller:

```
@PostMapping(value="/AdminCreateUser", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public void createUser(@RequestParam String username, @RequestParam String password, @RequestParam (required = false) String[] roles,
                           @RequestParam (required = false) String[] groups){
        User user = new User(username, password);
        if(roles != null){
            Set<Role> roleList = roleService.findRoles(roles);
            if(roleList.size() > 0){
                user.setRoles(roleList);
            }
        }
        if(groups != null){
            Set<Group> groupList = groupService.findGroups(groups);
            for(Group group: groupList){
                group.addMember(user);
                groupRepository.save(group);
            }
        }
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
```

However I get `Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'username' is not present]`. Does Jackson not bind matching elements of the json string array to the request parameters? If not, how do I do this? I want to save myself the effort of sending each form field as separate data

Answer (score 0):

The output of serialize array will be,

```
[
   {
     "name" : "username",
     "value" : "test"
   },...
]
```

Then change the java code as,

```
public void createUser(@RequestBody String body){
```

Convert string to JSONObject and handle it as JSON. Then this will work.
If you want to handle with Request Param.
Change the content-type to multipart/form-data and post it directly to the API.

Comment: If I convert it to String i have no way of splitting each value because some of the fields may or may not be present (required = false)

Comment: You can validate the value on the server side right using the name field?

Answer (score 0):

There are two way.

1. By using application/json

Modify your js code like this.

```
$("#modalForm").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
    
    //convert form data to json array of Object(name value pair)
    data = []
    var x = $(this).serializeArray();
    $.each(x, function(i, field){
      var name = field.name; var value = field.value;
      data[i] = {name : value};
    });
    
    
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: form.attr('action'),
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(data), 
        success: function(data)
        {
            table.row('.selected').ajax.reload();
        }
    });

});
```

Modify your controller

```
public void createUser(@RequestBody CreateUserDto createUserRequest){
```

2. If you want to use request param change content-type to multipart/form-data.

Comment: I don't think using a DTO will work for me. The form contains values that are not directly related to a User entity and hence it would not be possible to map the request body

Comment: To map DTO to entity even if it have different fields you can use MapStruct or you can get value from DTO using getters and process according to your requirement.